# Regex Valid Twitter Mention

Tags: regex, twitter, pattern-matching, preg-match

I'm trying to find a regex that matches if a Tweet it's a true mention. To be a mention, the string can't start with "@" and can't contain "RT" (case insensitive) and "@" must start the word.

In the examples I commented the desired output

Some examples:

```
function search($strings, $regexp) {
    $regexp;
    foreach ($strings as $string) {
        echo "Sentence: \"$string\" <- " .
        (preg_match($regexp, $string) ? "MATCH" : "NO MATCH") . "\n";
    }
}

$strings = array(
"Hi @peter, I like your car ", // <- MATCH
"@peter I don't think so!", //<- NO MATCH: the string it's starting with @ it's a reply
"Helo!! :@ how are you!", // NO MATCH <- it's not a word, we need @(word) 
"Yes @peter i'll eat them this evening! RT @peter: hey @you, do you want your pancakes?", // <- NO MATCH "RT/rt" on the string , it's a RT
"Helo!! ineed@aser.com how are you!", //<- NO MATCH, it doesn't start with @
"@peter is the best friend you could imagine. RT @juliet: @you do you know if @peter it's awesome?" // <- NO MATCH starting with @ it's a reply and RT
);
echo "Example 1:\n";
search($strings,  "/(?:[[:space:]]|^)@/i");
```

Current output:

```
Example 1:
Sentence: "Hi @peter, I like your car " <- MATCH
Sentence: "@peter I don't think so!" <- MATCH
Sentence: "Helo!! :@ how are you!" <- NO MATCH
Sentence: "Yes @peter i'll eat them this evening! RT @peter: hey @you, do you want your pancakes?" <- MATCH
Sentence: "Helo!! ineed@aser.com how are you!" <- MATCH
Sentence: "@peter is the best friend you could imagine. RT @juliet: @you do you know if @peter it's awesome?" <- MATCH
```

EDIT:

> I need it in regex beacause it can be used on MySQL and anothers
>   languages too. Im am not looking for any username. I only want to know
>   if the string it's a mention or not.

Comment: `RT` case insensitive, like rt at the end of abort?

Comment: "rt" must be a word, and could be followed by ":" Ex:  RT|rt|rt:|RT:|rT:| are valid

Comment: so `abort: now` is a valid retweet?

Comment: For anyone looking for a general purpose pattern to find mentions, the `EXTRACT_MENTIONS` pattern used by Twitter themselves is available [here](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text-java/blob/master/src/com/twitter/Regex.java).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a regex that should work:

```
/^(?!.*\bRT\b)(?:.+\s)?@\w+/i
```

Explanation:

```
/^             //start of the string
(?!.*\bRT\b)   //Verify that rt is not in the string.
(?:.*\s)?      //Find optional chars and whitespace the
                  //Note: (?: ) makes the group non-capturing.
@\w+           //Find @ followed by one or more word chars.
/i             //Make it case insensitive.
```

Comment: +1 for the explanation, but you should change .*@ to .+@ to verify that you have at least one char before the @.

Comment: It works, thank you very much. But with the new example with an email it matches and it must not:
    Sentence: Helo!! ineed@aser.com how are you! <- MATCH

Comment: @LDK Okay, I added a check for a space char before the @

Comment: @Jacob it's no valid with the examples, but you give me some ideas :D

`/^(?!.*\bRT\b).+\s@([A-Za-z0-9_])/i`

Comment: [A-Za-z0-9_] is the same as \w. The problem with Jacobs solution is just that he put the \s on the wrong side of the @ :)

Comment: It also stops working when you have dot within or after the username, i.e. @user.123, which is permissible in Twitter.

Answer (score 13):

This regexp might work a bit better: `/\B\@([\w\-]+)/gim`

Here's a jsFiddle example of it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/2TQsx/96/

Comment: Seems not to handle two when `@` is preceded by whitespace or when a stray `@` is found in a string which a following valid `@mention`.

Comment: @JoshHabdas hmm, example works for me when I test both of the things you listed - let me know if you can reproduce.

Comment: I blame Babel. Here's what I [ended up using](https://git.habd.as/jhabdas/xanthippe/src/branch/master/lib/xanthippe.js#L8) which was based on this response.

Answer (score 3):

I have found that this is the best way to find mentions inside of a string in javascript. I don't know exactly how i would do the RT's but I think this might help with part of the problem.

```
var str = "@jpotts18 what is up man? Are you hanging out with @kyle_clegg";
var pattern = /@[A-Za-z0-9_-]*/g;
str.match(pattern);
["@jpotts18", "@kyle_clegg"]
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess something like this will do it:

```
^(?!.*?RT\s).+\s@\w+
```

Roughly translated to:

At the beginning of string, look ahead to see that RT\s is not present, then find one or more of characters followed by a @ and at least one letter, digit or underscore.

Comment: Now it does not match emails.

Answer (score 0):

Twitter has published the regex they use in their [twitter-text](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text) library. They have other language versions posted as well on GitHub.

Comment: Your answer is a good reason for why we don't post links only. You should have given us the regex here with the link. With the link broken, your answer is useless.

Comment: I'm not posting 232 lines of code. It's an entire class not a one liner. Link updated, took 5 seconds to find it.

Comment: aaaaand it's broken again.

Answer (score 0):

A simple but works correctly even if the scraping tool has appended some special characters sometimes: `(?<![\w])@[\S]*\b`. This worked for me

Comment: Why do you put `\w` and `\S` in character class? The `\b` at the end is useless and may cause wrong match, what do you want to mach with it?